# Calculate a Bearing from DMS

Tags: swift, coordinates

I have some difficulty to get this to work. I tried many different formulas and always end up with the same result.
Based from the same data (coordinates) I can calculate the distance. But not the bearing.
I run out of ideas and keywords to find a formula that will work.

Thank you all for helping out!

```
let fLat = d2r(degrees: lat)
let fLng = d2r(degrees: long)
let tLat = d2r(degrees: lat2)
let tLng = d2r(degrees: long2)

let a = CGFloat(sin(fLng - tLng) * cos(tLat))
let b = CGFloat(cos(fLat) * sin(tLat) - sin(fLat) * cos(tLat) * cos(fLng-tLng))

let bearing = atan2(a,b)

func d2r(degrees : Double) -> Double {
    return degrees * Double.pi / 180.0
}
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to calculate bearing on a perfect sphere, given your formulae (which superficially seem correct) - what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: I think I need to add the difference of angle between the North and my heading. The thing is everywhere I saw an example, I couldn't figure it out how they get this angle. Probably not smart enough!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the example in the comments, you seem to be suffering simply from a sign error:

> CYWG = N 49 54 6 W097 14 4, CYYQ = N58 44 4 W094 03 9, I should have
>   an heading of 11 degrees True.

```
let lat = 49.0 + 54.0 / 60.0 + 6.0 / 3600.0
let long = -(97.0 + 14.0 / 60.0 + 4.0 / 3600.0)
let lat2 = 58.0 + 44.0 / 60.0 + 4.0 / 3600.0
let long2 = -(94.0 + 3.0 / 60.0 + 9.0 / 3600.0)

let fLat = d2r(degrees: lat)
let fLng = d2r(degrees: long)
let tLat = d2r(degrees: lat2)
let tLng = d2r(degrees: long2)

let a = sin(fLng - tLng) * cos(tLat)
let b = cos(fLat) * sin(tLat) - sin(fLat) * cos(tLat) * cos(fLng - tLng)

let bearing = atan2(a,b)
bearing * 180.0 / Double.pi // -10.58473709161037
```

so the answer from your code is ~ -11. Checking with my own implementation of [Vincenty's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty's_formulae) I get the accurate azimuth to be

```
let (d, az, raz) = vincentyInverse(p1, to: p2, ellipsoid: .wgs84)
az.toDegrees // 10.61078843895496
```

so it looks as if all that is wrong with your formula is that you have subtracted tLng from fLng instead of *vice versa*. Replacing `fLng - tLng` in both places you use it by `tLng - fLng` gives you 10.58 as your answer.

Of course, if you want accurate bearings, you should use Vincenty or Robbins or some other formula that takes account of the non-spherical figure of the earth - the formula you are using is only accurate on a perfect sphere...

Comment: I am not sure If I understand? You are saying if I have 0 than mean 0 = 90 degrees East, and 180 will be 270 degrees West? Using your calculation I have 0.095946.... for an heading of 276

Comment: 0 = 90 + 180 = 270 + (0.095946 x 60) == 276

Comment: I tried with an other number 1.7555 and I couldn't make it work?

Comment: You need to give us examples of what results you are getting for what inputs, and what you expected to get. Without that, we are just guessing.

Comment: CYWG = N 49 54 6 W097 14 4, CYYQ = N58 44 4 W094 03 9, I should have an heading of 11 degrees True.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Using your formula and replacing fLng with the tang, i get the correct heading going north and East but west and south, I get a mirror results. 165 instead of 195. And sorry But I didn't understand the VincentyInverse, don't know how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Grimxn. I was very stock on this one. I was also able to answer to my last question.

```
        if bearing < 0 {
      HeadingHolder = (bearing * 180.0 / Double.pi) + 360
    }else{
       HeadingHolder = (bearing * 180.0 / Double.pi)
    }
```